# Connect to remote databse using cordova/phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cordova

I can't login to the database located in the PC's server.
I'm using Cordova/Phonegap.

That's my code.
HTML:

```
    <head>
        <title>Login Form Using jQuery - Demo Preview</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <!-- Include CSS File Here -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
        <!-- Include CSS File Here -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    </head>
    <body style="background-color: red;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main">
                <form class="form" method="post" action="#">
                    <h2>Create Login Form Using jQuery</h2>
                    <label>Email :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="demail" id="email">
                    <label>Password :</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                    <input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").click(function () {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

// Checking for blank fields.
        if (email === '' || password === '') {
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("border", "2px solid red");
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("box-shadow", "0 0 3px red");
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        } else {
            $.post("http://192.168.0.110/login.php", {email1: email, password1: password},
            function (data) {

                if (data === 'Invalid Email.......') {
                    $('input[type="text"]').css({"border": "2px solid red", "box-shadow": "0 0 3px red"});
                    $('input[type="password"]').css({"border": "2px solid #00F5FF", "box-shadow": "0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
                    alert(data);
                } else if (data === 'Email or Password is wrong...!!!!') {
                    $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border": "2px solid red", "box-shadow": "0 0 3px red"});
                    alert(data);
                } else if (data === 'Successfully Logged in...') {
                    $("form")[0].reset();
                    $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border": "2px solid #00F5FF", "box-shadow": "0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

login.php (on my localhost)

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing connection with server..
$db = mysql_select_db("college", $connection); // Selecting Database.
$email=$_POST['email1']; // Fetching Values from URL.
$password= sha1($_POST['password1']); // Password Encryption, If you like you can also leave sha1.
// check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // sanitizing email(Remove unexpected symbol like <,>,?,#,!, etc.)
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo "Invalid Email.......";
}else{
// Matching user input email and password with stored email and password in database.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");
$data = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($data==1){
echo "Successfully Logged in...";
}else{
echo "Email or Password is wrong...!!!!";
}
}
mysql_close ($connection); // Connection Closed.
?>
```

When i hit the login button, nothing happens.
I tried adding an alert but it in $.post() but didnt showed.

any ideas guys?

Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: that's too much to read, simplify it down to the smallest part of the code that still reproduces the problem. and format the php.

Comment: setup an error function in your ajax callback so that we can find the errors easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `$.post` with this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://192.168.0.110/login.php',
        data:{email1: email, password1: password},
        success: function(data) {
          alert("from server"+data);
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
        }
      });
```

and trace the output of the `error` function which will help us to find the errors easliy